# How to establish a VPN connection (Cisco IPSec Xauth PSK) within my android app instead of activating it through Android's inbuilt VPN tool?

Tags: java, android, openvpn, android-vpn-service

I am developing an app where I have to connect to a remote server through VPN. Presently I am using Android's inbuilt tool for VPN configuration and connection (Settings>More>VPN>...), which I have to activate and deactivate several times during the use of the app (the server blocks other internet connection when connected though this VPN, so I only want to establish it once in a while).

Here is the configuration necessary for that VPN connection:
Name: arbitrary
Type: **IPSec Xauth PSK**
Server Address: known
IPSec Identifier: known
IPSec Pre-shared key: known
Username: known
Password: known

If I understood right, I could either run a background service to establish the connection and then activate/deactivate from the foreground/UI activity, or maybe just have an inbuilt method if that activity/class to establish the VPN connection when necessary.

I also know there is VpnService class but I think it is much more complex than what I need.
I have seen suggestions on using OpenVPN source code but I get lost on where to pick it up.
This as an example:
[Android: Sample Code to connect to VPN in Android 4.0 using VPNService API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13177522/android-sample-code-to-connect-to-vpn-in-android-4-0-using-vpnservice-api)

Is it possible to have this inbuilt VPN? Could someone give me a hint on how to code it? Thanks in advance

EDIT:
I also have found here that it is not possible configure an L2TP/IPSec, would it also apply to IPSec Xauth PSK??
[Create L2TP/IPSec VPN base on VpnService programmatically in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278313/create-l2tp-ipsec-vpn-base-on-vpnservice-programmatically-in-android)

Comment: I would only need to understand which is the way to go, any help given is appreciated!

Comment: I am currently setting up the service (new to me, Java beginner) from which the VPN could be activated/deactivated.

Comment: In the following post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50021979/how-to-create-ipsec-l2tp-psk-vpn-for-android
It is said IPSec and L2TP cannot be accessed (Android's inbuilt VPN tools) in latest versions of Android. Are they accessible in Android 7.0 for example?

Comment: I keep finding people asking the same (or very similar) questions, still not fully answered, in this case also with L2TP/IPSec:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56966665/how-to-extend-vpnservice-to-open-an-l2tp-ipsec-connection-in-android-programmati